# Passing a parameter from an async function to another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to NodeJS and scraping with JS. How can I pass a parameter from an async function to a another file.

```
//file 1
async function getToken(){
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text()) //this is the paramater I want to use in file 2
}
```

```
//file 2
//const { ConsoleMessage } = require("puppeteer");
//const response = require("./dbc")

const scraperObject = {
  url : url,
  async scraper(browser){
    try{
      let page = await browser.newPage();
      console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
      await page.goto(this.url);
      await page.$eval("textarea#g-recaptcha-response", text => text.innerHTML = response)
}
```

Technically, file 2 would run and then await for file 1 response.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try importing `getToken` function in file2 and then call it from there. 

Also, you will either use async/await or `then`

Comment: its nether shown how `getToken()` is called nor how the parameter of interes would be used in the file 2 code

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
//file 1
// export features declared earlier
export { myStr };
const myStr;

async function getToken(){
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => myStr = response.text()) //this is the paramater I want to use in file 2
}


//file 2
import { myStr } form 'yourFile1name.js'

const scraperObject = {
  url : url,
  async scraper(browser){
    try{
      let page = await browser.newPage();
      console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
      await page.goto(this.url);
      await page.$eval("textarea#g-recaptcha-response", text => text.innerHTML = response)
}
```

Accordin how to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) in the documentation

Comment: hm, doesn't seem `getToken()` is called anywhere, thus `myStr` will never be set ...

Comment: how is it set is up to the OP. The question is about how to pass it. Its not shown neither how the param is used in the file 2 :/